# How to find a document with an element's value greater than size of array?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I want to find a document with `x` larger than the size of the array `y`. I'm doing this:

```
db.find(x: { $gt: { $size: "$y" } })
```

Doesn't find anything. What is wrong?

The last document should be returned:

```
{x: 0, y: [0, 1]}
{x: 1, y: [0, 1]}
{x: 2, y: [0, 1]}
{x: 3, y: [0, 1]} # 3 is larger than 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [$expr](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/) to compare two fields from the same document in your query:

```
db.col.find({ $expr: { $gt: [ "$x", { $size: "$y" } ] } })
```